# Why is Windows "stuck" on the Welcome screen for so long?

Tags: windows-7, boot, login

I use Windows 7 with a laptop specifications processor core ([Core i3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Core#Core_i3)), 2 GB DDR3 RAM, the remaining capacity on the system partition (25 GB).
I do not know why the "welcome screen" takes a long time (about 40 sec), but yesterday only took about 10 sec.,

[image]

I tried to defragment the disk and do a virus & spyware scan with antivirus, but still the "Welcome screen" comes along.

How do I get the welcome screen to pass by faster when Windows boots up?

Comment: try running autoruns and look for things that its trying to load but arn't there

Comment: how? and if it has no effect on the system? please let me know

Comment: See Oliver's answer

Comment: My money is on autoruns, hence the comment only, but try Auslogics defrag to. They have profiles which allow you to optimise your hard drive for with different profiles such as for boot speed, system file performance, application performance etc.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Logon Scripts

One cause of this (that I experience myself) is certain scripts that are executed on log on. You can see these with [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx).

[image]

As you can see, there is a group policy script referenced in my system configuration. Sadly, I connect to that domain through VPN which isn't active when I log on.

So, the script is **never** found and causes a noticeable delay on the *Welcome* screen.

I noticed this after I joined the SBS domain.

Even if this is not your problem, Autoruns should help you track down what is causing the delay.

### Network Shares

After reading the blog post [The Case of the Veeerrry Slow Logons](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2012/07/02/3506849.aspx), I learned that similar issues can result from having mapped network shares that aren't available when logging on.

Comment: precisely what i was talking about in the comments.

Answer (score 12):

The problem is the desktop background.

If it is set to a solid color, it takes about 30 seconds to login. If I set it to a picture, the login takes about 3 seconds.

It is the strangest behavior, but I have tested it on two computers and it fixes the problem.  If I put it back to a solid color, it goes back to 30 seconds to login.

Several people on [another Windows Seven Forums website](http://www.sevenforums.com/performance-maintenance/22147-slow-login.html) also confirm this.

Comment: ... wow, that's good to know. Wonder though how drawing a single color is more intensive than drawing a picture.

Comment: Yes. I've had this problem before myself. I thought it was only a Windows XP thing, though. I haven't seen this behavior on Windows 7 if I recall correctly.

Comment: [Why would a solid wallpaper cause a Windows PC a long time to login?](http://superuser.com/questions/886866/why-would-a-solid-wallpaper-cause-a-windows-pc-a-long-time-to-login)

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a very quantitative way of measuring what is taking up all of this time, I would recommend getting the [soluto beta](http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/Soluto-Download-161601.html).

After a boot, it will tell what is in boot, in addition to how much time each program contributed to the boot (in tenths of a second) in addition to giving you a way to remove that program or other item from your boot (in most cases).

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me, did you by any chance install VirtualBox?
After I installed a "portable" version of it and restarted I couldn't log in (it took forever on the welcome screen).

How to fix:

1. Enter windows in safe mode (hold F8 when starting) and delete all of the following:
   `C:\Windows\system32\drivers\vbox*.sys` (`*` means anything that starts with vbox)
2. Enter your registry (run regedit) and delete all of the folders that start with VBox at the following location: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\VBox*`
3. Restart

After this I still ran into trouble getting networking to work. Just reinstall your network card drivers.