# Why would a solid wallpaper cause a Windows PC a long time to login?

Tags: windows-7, desktop-customization

I have been using Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit in my [Dell Inspiron 620s](http://www.dell.com/us/p/inspiron-620s/pd) (Intel Pentium Dual core, 2GB DDR3 RAM). My PC used to take a long time to login and it’s only for my admin account; other user account works well.

Then I found out that the slow login was due to the wallpaper I used; I used a simple, black solid color wallpaper available on the system. But when I changed it to something else, my PC became fast.

I just want to know why it is so?

Comment: @JakeGould I didn't approved the edit I hope, it is confusing about the wallpaper which causes the problem. Actually the walpaper causing the problem is "Black Solid Colour".

Comment: There is no logical reason why a color only desktop would cause a problem, that style was used in way earlier desktops, that and simple patterns.   There are though some specalty colors that have been used/are recognised as transparency, like 100% majenta has had some interesting effects in earlier windows versions.  So I would wonder if something that is the tiniest bit off from full 0,0,0 black would change anything? Try a R02 G01 B03 in the More..  Are all solids causing the problem?  Easy enough to use a black exact resolution picture , and make sure that tiling is set to center, or fill.

Comment: @Psycogeek I too was wondering about this, but it is tru. I do not know about the other solid colours because I haven't used them( I use black to lower the eye strain). But, if I put a black image created in an image editor, it works well.

Comment: capture 2 boot traces (http://pastebin.com/CYGqRZXE), 1 with a wallpaper and 1 without a wallpaper ad share them (compressed as 7z/RAR to reduce the size). I'll compare them and look if I can find the cause of the difference.

Comment: I've experienced the same but in a domain environment. Solid colours vs. wallpaper. Solid colour increased our logon times incredibly. The way we got around this was to use a small .jpg of our desired colour and set the wallpaper to stretch so it fits all screen resolutions. Logon time is much better.

Comment: @BigChris there was a bug in the RTM, which was fixed via a hotfix, so this should be fixed in Windows 7 Sp1: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/977346/en-US

Comment: have you captured the 2 traces?

Comment: @magicandre1981 I do not want to install a third party software for this purpose, is there any windows alternative? Besides, I have changed the wallpaper and the problem no longer exists.

Comment: this is no 3rd party tool, it is from Microsoft which Microsoft internally uses to trace Windows to make it faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solutions:

1. There is a Hot Fix [available](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/977346) (Thanks to **magicandre1981** ).
2. Change the wallpaper from solid colour to an *image* that has a solid colour.

   ---

Another Solution(Requires editing [Windows Registry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry)):

Configure the value of the DelayedDesktopSwitchTimeout registry entry. This value determines the time-out interval of a session before Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2 switches between sessions.

To configure the value of the *DelayedDesktopSwitchTimeout* registry entry, follow these steps:

1. Click Start[image: Start] button, type regedit in the **Search programs and files** box, and then press ENTER.
2. Locate the following registry subkey:
   **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System**
3. Double-click the **DelayedDesktopSwitchTimeout** registry entry.
4. In the Value data box, type **5**, and then click OK.

This answer is reproduced from [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/977346) Microsoft support article.